# comparing python datetime to mysql datetime

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, compare

I'm a complete beginner, I have a test mysql db set up. I am currently trying to check if the backup start time listed in the database is before 12pm on the current day. The time was entered into the table using the following:

```
UPDATE Clients SET backup_started=NOW() WHERE id=1;
```

What I am currently trying is:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today12am = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second =0,)
dbu.cursor.execute('SELECT id, company_name, backup_started,\
backup_finished FROM Clients WHERE backup_started>' + today12am)
data = dbu.cursor.fetchone()
print (data)
```

I understand that it is trying to compare a datetime.datetime to a string and this is where it is having problems. My question is what is the best way to accomplish this?

error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.datetime' objects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your query *parameterized*:

```
dbu.cursor.execute("""
    SELECT 
        id, company_name, backup_started, backup_finished 
    FROM 
        Clients 
    WHERE 
        backup_started > %s""", (today12pm, ))
```

Answer (score 1):

use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
dbu.cursor.execute('SELECT id, company_name, backup_started,\
backup_finished FROM Clients WHERE backup_started> %s' %today12pm.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

check that the format is correct